# How can HashSet::add be accepted as an ObjectIntConsumer?

Tags: java, functional-interface

It seems that following line is a valid implementation for collecting a stream of integers in Java:

```
IntStream.range(1, 100)
    .collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::add, HashSet::addAll);
```

But when I take into account the collect method signature in IntStream class that is

```
collect(Supplier<R> supplier,  ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,  BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)
```

, I can not understand how can *HashSet::add* be passed to collect method where an *ObjIntConsumer* is expected, since *ObjIntConsumer* is expecting two arguments

```
void accept(T t, int value);
```

, but *HashSet::add* accepts only one argument!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent lambda expression for `HashSet::add` in your code is:

```java
(HashSet<Integer> t, int value) -> t.add(value)
```

In other words, the `ObjIntConsumer` is accepting both the container (in this case a `HashSet`) and the value to be added to that container.